# Looking to pull out data between two string

Tags: python

In Python, I am trying to pull out information with regex between two strings. I think it would be better to give an example.

```
<stuff>
1
2
3
4
</stuff>

<stuff>
5
7
8
9
</stuff>
```

I am trying to pull one of these containers* at a time and place them in a seperate file.  I have found out how to pull the content between eg,5 6 7 8, and pull all of the records at the same time(in bash), but have not gotten the full container including the regex placed in a variable or a file, something I can work with.

So I would want to collect between and including <stuff> and < /stuff>

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.  I am trying to work in python2 for this.

Comment: If you need to parse data in XML format, you can try using facilities from `xml.etree.ElementTree` module - http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: What does the asterisk after "containers" signify? Also, your input is `5 7 8 9`, but your output is `5 6 7 8`, is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks for that but unfornately that is not working for what I need. Specifically this is for taking a large httpd.conf file with many vhosts... so ... <VirtualHost> ServerName test123 DocumentRoot /test123 </VirtualHost> <VirtualHost> ServerName 123543 DocumentRoot /123534 </VirtualHost> and creating seperate files with the individual containers in it, so one of the new files or variables would contain "<VirtualHost> ServerName 123543 DocumentRoot /123534 </VirtualHost>"... Hope that clears it up, please let me know if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to parse data in XML format, you can try using facilities from [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML
single_item_data = XML("<stuff>1 2 3</stuff>").text
```

If you have some nested elements, you can do something like this below:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML

test_input_xml = '''
<lotsOfStuff>
   <stuff>
   1
   2
   3
   4
   </stuff>

   <stuff>
   5
   7
   8
   9
   </stuff>
</lotsOfStuff>
'''

test_input = XML(test_input_xml)
stuffs = test_input.findall("stuff")

for stuff in stuffs:
   element_text = stuff.text
   print element_text
```

Comment: Thanks for that but unfornately that is not working for what I need.  Specifically this is for taking a large httpd.conf file with many vhosts... so ...

<VirtualHost>
ServerName test123
DocumentRoot /test123
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost>
ServerName 123543
DocumentRoot /123534
</VirtualHost>

and creating seperate files with the individual containers in it, so one of the new files or variables would contain "<VirtualHost>
ServerName 123543
DocumentRoot /123534
</VirtualHost>"...  

Hope that clears it up, please let me know if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to present a simplified picture of grabbing data out of an HTML page, then I would strongly recommend against regex [lookup in SO, for why].

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/). Much better, much more powerful.